# Parsing a long string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a long string using regex in python.
The string is like that:

```
 Output = "Name:AmelieAge:30Nationality:english"
```

Basically, the field names are fixed but I can have a more complex string with repetitive data for example:

```
  Output = "Name:AmelieAge:30Nationality:englishName:NikeAge:20Nationality:frenshName:davidAge:50Nationality:Irish"
```

I looking for a way to have structured data like this:

```
Name:Amelie
Age:30
Nationality:english

Name:David
Age:50
Nationality:Irish
```

If you have any suggestions concerning regex to use in order to parse this long string.

**FYI:** the string size is aleatory

Comment: does the string always have name ,age and nationality

Comment: Do you already know the field names?

Comment: Please let us know what you tried. This does not seem to hard unless the input is not always like the one you provided.

Comment: You have to give some more informations, eg. if the field names are fix or follow a specific logic

Comment: See [Meta about Regex questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]+\:[\w\d][a-z\d]+", Output)
['Name:Amelie', 'Age:30', 'Nationality:english']
```

I supposed all keys start with a Capital letter, and Values has no capital letter except for the first one.

Comment: This will fail with a composed name like `Jean Pierre`

Comment: `Jean Pierre` is already an ambiguity cause you may understand it also as Value Key like in the OP example `AmelieAge`

Comment: except that `Pierre` isn't followed with `:` or the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall("[A-Z]\w+:[\d\w]+(?=[A-Z]\w+|$)", Output)
```

Using a lookahead assertion is the best way to go. This regex will capture strings that starts with capital letter and continue as lower or upper case, then `:` and after that it will capture any digits or letters until there left a character group which starts with capital and continues with letters or until the end of text is reached.

That will capture the groups correctly, even in the situations like told in @bigOTHER's comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of dictionaries as follows from the string:

```
import re, itertools

Output = "Name:AmelieAge:30Nationality:englishName:NikeAge:20Nationality:frenshName:davidAge:50Nationality:Irish"

entries = []
i_split = iter(re.split("(Name|Nationality|Age):", Output)[1:])

for entry in iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(i_split, 6)), []):
    i_entry = iter(entry)
    d_entry = {k:next(i_entry) for k in i_entry}
    entries.append(d_entry) 

# Display the whole list
print entries
print

# Display entries one at a time
for entry in entries:
    for k, v in entry.items():
        print "{}:{}".format(k,v)
    print
```

This would give you an output of:

```
[{'Nationality': 'english', 'Age': '30', 'Name': 'Amelie'}, {'Nationality': 'frensh', 'Age': '20', 'Name': 'Nike'}, {'Nationality': 'Irish', 'Age': '50', 'Name': 'david'}]

Nationality:english
Age:30
Name:Amelie

Nationality:frensh
Age:20
Name:Nike

Nationality:Irish
Age:50
Name:david
```